# How can I connect to ejabberd's Mnesia database with a separate script?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mnesia

I'm trying to insert affiliation data into ejabberd's Mnesia databse from a separate script. I'm an Erlang beginner, and while I can figure out how to create and use a separate Mnesia database, I can't figure out how to connect to ejabberd's. Using the same "-mnesia dir" does not seem to suffice.

Answer (score 5):

The question reduces to the question of how to make rpc calls in Erlang.

1. Ensure that ejabberd is running with either a fully-qualified hostname or IP address for host part of the node. This is specified in my installation as EJABBERD_NODE in /etc/ejabberd/ejabberdctl.cfg. If you do have to change the hostname in this step, consult https://git.process-one.net/ejabberd/mainline/blobs/raw/v2.1.10/doc/guide.html#htoc79 ("Change Computer Hostname").
2. Start your shell or script with -name or -sname and use a host with the same restriction as above.
3. You're ready to use Erlang's built-in RPC. For example:

(from your shell or script)

```
Cookie = 'YOUR_EJABBERD_COOKIE'. % mine was found in /var/lib/ejabberd/.erlang.cookie
EjabberdNode = 'ejabberd@127.0.0.1'. % or whatever you set as EJABBERD_NODE
erlang:set_cookie(EjabberdNode, Cookie).
net_adm:ping(EjabberdNode).
rpc:call(EjabberdNode, mnesia, system_info, [tables]).
```

Answer (score 2):

just use command **ejabberdctl debug**

```
mnesia:info(). %to overview mnesia 
mnesia:schema(schema). %see table named schema`s detail
```